# DropDown Selected Value JQuery Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#<%= chkCheckedSame.ClientID %>').change(function () {

                    if (document.getElementById('<%=chkCheckedSame.ClientID %>').checked) {

                        $('#<%=ShippingFirstName.ClientID %>').val
($('#<%=BillingFirstName.ClientID %>').val()); //working
                        $('#<%=ShippingLastName.ClientID %>').val
($('#<%=BillingLastName.ClientID %>').val());//working

                        alert($('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %>').val());
                        $('#<%=ShippingCountry.ClientID %> :selected').val
($('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %> :selected').val()); //Notworking

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

What i'm tried:

Try1:

```
$('#<%=ShippingCountry.ClientID %> :selected').val
    ($('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %> :selected').val());
```

Try2:

```
$('#<%=ShippingCountry.ClientID %> :selected').text
    ($('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %> :selected').text());
```

Try3:

```
$('#<%=ShippingCountry.ClientID %>').val
        ($('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %>').val());
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jqpv8t54/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use option with selected.

For value of option

```
 ($('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
```

For text of option

```
 $('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %> option:selected').text();
```

You may have other thing that are stopping the desired output, e.g.
`$('#<%=ShippingFirstName.ClientID %>').val` will be syntax error. `$('#<%=ShippingFirstName.ClientID %>').val` should be `$('#<%=ShippingFirstName.ClientID %>').val();`

Comment: `($('#<%=ShippingCountry.ClientID %> option:selected').val(($('#<%=BillingCountry.ClientID %> option:selected').val()))); ` not working.

Comment: when i'm using it, the whole jquey not working, can you tell me what's i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may have other thing that are stopping the desired output, e.g.  $('#<%=ShippingFirstName.ClientID %>').val will be syntax error. val should be val().  Test the things one by one.

Comment: here, i'm trying to set one `dropdown` selected value from another one. that's why i'm using `val('value_from_another')`

Comment: Can you do that with generated html on jsfiddle ?

Comment: I could not update the fiddle dont know why, but this is working. $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("hello..");
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedSame').change(function () {
        var CountryVal = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BillingCountry").val();
        alert(CountryVal);
    });
});